# Entity Relationship Design: Mutually Exclusive Has-A Relationship

Tags: oop, entity, domain-driven-design, relationship, invariants

I'm determining the best design approach for an object that can have a relationship with different types of other objects. But can only belong to one type at a time. A mutually-exclusive one-to-many has-a relationship is the best phrase I can think of to describe the situation.

Example:

I have both Projects and Procedures. Each can contain multiple Tasks. A Task can belong to a Project or a Procedure, but never more than one at the same time. A Task can be moved from a Project to a Procedure and vice-versa.

So at any one time Task has a one-to-many relationship with a Project, or a one-to-many relationship with a Procedure.

At the moment, I'm considering a Task as such:

```
   class Task(id, name, project_id, procedure_id):
       if project_id and procedure_id:
           throw Exception("A Task can not be assigned to a Project and a Procedure at the same time")

       self.id = id
       self.name = name
       self.project_id = project_id
       self.procedure_id = procedure_id

   def move_to_project(project_id):
       self.procedure_id = None
       self.project_id = project_id

   ...
```

Task would protect the invariant that it can only belong to a a single Project or Procedure. Factory methods on Project and Procedure can create the Task with the relevant relationship ID.

A Task is not in the same aggregate with either, so I want to model the relationship by identity.

It seems to me that the only way to protect this invariant is to model Task this way. Otherwise I'd end up with a giant Procedures/Projects/Tasks aggregate.

Does this seem like a sane approach or anyone have any advice on alternative design approaches that might be worth exploring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have TaskService.AssignToProject() and TaskService.AssigneToProcedure() methods on TaskService application layer. If Task is a separate aggregate, it means it can live its own life without Procedure or Project. They can be empty for some period of time. ProcedureId or ProjectId should be assigned when TaskService.AssignToProject() or TaskService.AssigneToProcedure() are called. So in your TaskService.AssignToProject() you get Task and Project from db, and call task.AssignTo(project). Then you verify if ProcedureId is null and do what you need (throw an exception or UnassignFromProcedure()). After assignment is done, you raise TaskAssignedToProject domain event, catch it and in ANOTHER TRANSACTION call ProjectService.CommitTask(). That whould add that task to an internal collection of CommittedTasks on Project aggregate.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I plan to also include convenience factory methods such as project.add_task() in the instance when you would like to create a task and have it associated immediately. I like the addition of the event to create an internal collection of Tasks. I believe I've seen something similar in Vaughn Vernon's AgilePM example with BackLogs. Sounds like I'm on the right track. Thank you for the confirmation.

Comment: @Steven Exactly. You can't reuse Task class for CommittedTasks in Project aggregate, cause it may need totally unique behavior, related to ProjectAssignedTask, for example some points calculation, based on which they would be grouped or sorted. project.add_task() - Make sure you get rid of 'Create, Update, Delete' terms. Use Ubiquitous Language. Feels like 'add' is a smell :)

Answer (score 1):

If a task cannot be associated to a project and to a procedure at the same time, I wouldn't have a constructor with the two ids. I would have one for project id and another one for procedure id. And I would do it with factory methods named according to the UL. That way you construct a task associated to either a project or to a procedure, but not both.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Python so am unable to use method overloading on the constructor. But yes, the factory methods to create the Task would do this. ie Project would have a factory method assign_task(task_id, task_name). The Procedure method would have a similar factory method.